# Creating a new dataset out of existing datasets

Tags: r, merge

I have two datasets in R. Let's call them `a` and `b`.

`a` has three columns.

```
Customer age income
```

`b` has two columns

```
state country
```

How do I create a third dataset `c` which is a combination of `a` and `b` and looks like below.

```
Customer age income state country
```

Thank you

Comment: Do a & b have the same number of rows?  Are you really certain that row 5 in a corresponds to row 5 in b?

Answer (score 1):

If they have the same length and row are corresponding (first row is the same customer in a and b) then you can use `c <- cbind(a,b)`
If they doenst have the same length and doesnt correspond with each other than you need some kind of "key" to merge them with for example `merge()`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @jyr.

Found the answer:
install.packages("qpcR")

library(qpcR)

c <- qpcR:::cbind.na(a,b)